# PHP DOTENV unable to load env vars

Tags: php, environment-variables

I'm using [php dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) for env vars for my php application.

The readme says I can load `php dotenv` into my application with:

```
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

When I try to login, I get a 500 error. I tried `var_dump`ing my `$dotenv` var to see what it contains but I get nothing. Am I including this incorrectly?

/php/DbConnect.php:

```
<?php
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

$DB_HOST = getenv('DB_HOST');
$DB_USERNAME = getenv('DB_USERNAME');
$DB_PASSWORD = getenv('DB_PASSWORD');
$DB_DATABASE = getenv('DB_DATABASE');
```

---

My root/composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

My phpdotenv vendor files are:

- root/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php
- root/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Loader.php
- root/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Validator.php

In my root/php/DbConnect.php file:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

require 'vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php';
require 'vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Loader.php';
require 'vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Validator.php';
$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

$DB_HOST = getenv('DB_HOST');
    ...
```

Am I including correctly?

Comment: Are you including the file that contains the class via `include()` or `require()` etc?

Comment: @Rasclatt am I including correctly?

Answer (score 16):

Note that the [docs for DotENV](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) don't recommend using `getenv()` or `putenv()`. Instead, you should use `$_ENV['EXAMPLEVAR']`

So this is now the correct way:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

$DB_HOST = $_ENV['DB_HOST'];
```

In New Version:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    
# $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
# Replaced by following line
$dotEnv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
# and then rest of code as normal
$dotenv->load();

$DB_HOST = $_ENV['DB_HOST'];
```

Comment: Last line should use square brackets instead of parentheses. E.g, " $DB_HOST = $_ENV['DB_HOST']; "

Answer (score 5):

Using `getenv` and `putenv` are not thread safe. You should use `$_ENV['DB_HOT']` or `$_SERVER['DB_HOST']`. However, if you still need to use these functions, You can use `createUnsafeImmutable` static method. So the code will be

```
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createUnsafeImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

$DB_HOST = getenv('DB_HOST');
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 6 months old, but you do not need include/require as "phpdotenv" is loading Dotenv namespace. Check in vendor directory in composer directory what is auto loaded.

So all what you need is:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

$DB_HOST = getenv('DB_HOST');
```

Also make sure that load() method can find your .env file, if named differently, pass the name of the file to the load() method. 
Check docs here: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv  under Usage section.